# How do I move table caption placement in pandoc-converted docx file?

Tags: tables, pandoc, msword, latex-to-word

I have the following table:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 25 12:42:23 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & \# of Applicants \\ 
  \hline
African American &   5 \\ 
  Anglo &   1 \\ 
  Asian &   1 \\ 
  Asian American &   3 \\ 
  Black African &   0 \\ 
  Caucasian &  20 \\ 
  Chinese &   0 \\ 
  Chinese/Jewish &   1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Ethnicity of accepted applicants. These data represent 6 of the 6 seminars.} 
\label{tab:ethnicity}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to covert this `tex` to a `docx` file with `pandoc` as follows:

```
pandoc report.tex -f latex -t docx -s -o report.docx
```

But my issue is that in the resulting `docx` file, the table caption is placed above the table rather than below it (I like the caption-below-table placement of `pdfLaTeX`). Is there a way for me to make the caption go below the table in the `docx`?

I'm hoping something could be adjusted in the `pandoc` settings or even with Microsoft Word's "Styles". Importantly, I'd prefer an automated way to do this. I cannot manually reorder things in all the `tex` files I generate.